# Umbraco - Displaying All Blog Posts by a Specific User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I'm new to Umbraco and I've inherited a website that is mostly just put together from the CMS itself. I need to implement some more dynamic features in the existing website.

One of the issues is that I have a list of blog posts on a landing page. Below these I have hyperlinks for both the blogs posts's category and its author. If I click on the category name, I can pass the category id in the querystring and it will list all the posts related to that category. I need to do the same for the user. I can pass the user's category id, but it displays a message that "No posts were found".

I've read the Umbraco docs but nothing there really gave me any clues as to how I would accomplish this. I can get the name of the author to display when I pass the id in the querystring, but that's as far as I got.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(catID))
{ 
    <h1>@Umbraco.Field("onPageTitle", altFieldAlias: "pageName")</h1>
}
else
{
    var catPage = Umbraco.TypedContent(Convert.ToInt32(catID));
    if (catPage.HasValue("categoryPageTitle"))
    {
        <h1>@catPage.GetProperty("categoryPageTitle").Value</h1>
    }
    else
    { 
        <h1>@catPage.Name</h1>
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure my difficulties are due to a lack of understanding about how Umbraco works. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your content nodes so we can see where your blog posts are located? ( Printscreen of the content section in your backend of umbraco )

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have a content structure where you have a `Blog` node that contains `BlogItem` children.

Then you can create a `Macro partial view` in the `Developer section` of umbraco called `RenderBlogItemsOfCreator`.

**Partial View**

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@*

    This snippet renders the blog items based on the creator

*@

@{

    // Take the root blog node
    var blogRoot = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().DescendantsOrSelf("blogRootAlias").FirstOrDefault();

    // Get the user from the macro parameters
    var creatorUserId = int.Parse(Model.MacroParameters["userId"].ToString());

    // Get all blog children from this user that are visible and sort them from new to old
    var blogItems = blogRoot.Children.Where(x => x.CreatorId == creatorUserId && x.IsVisible()).OrderByDescending(y => y.CreateDate);

    foreach(var item in blogItems)
    {

        <div>@item.Name</div>

    }

}
```

**Macro**

Add the `userId` parameter to your macro of type numeric.

**Landing page**

Call the macro using:

```
Umbraco.RenderMacro("RenderBlogItemsOfCreator", new { userId = 1 })
```

The only thing you have to do is fill in this userId by taking it from the url and pass it through.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I got really busy with something else, but I will test them out on Monday and let you know what I find.